# Remover visualizacion de imagen dentro de un DIV

Tags: php, html, jquery

El problema que tengo es que puedo visualizar la imagen pero al momento de hacer click a remover se elimina todo el div `(<div id="preview"></div>)`
Le dejo  mi codigo para lo revisen ya que no me permite visualizar otras imagenes, gracias

```js
function readURL(input) {
     for(var i =0; i< input.files.length; i++){
         if (input.files[i]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
            
               var img = $('<img id="dynamic">');
               img.attr('src', e.target.result);
               img.attr('width','100');
               img.appendTo('#preview');  
               img.after('<a href="#" class="del">remove</a>'); 
                        }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
           }
        }
    }

    $("#imgUpload").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });


    $('#preview').on('click', '.del', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type="file" id="imgUpload" multiple/>
</form>
<div id="preview"></div>
```

Comment: porque no intentas colocar la etiqueta <img> dentro de tu <div id="preview"> y solo le quitas y le pones el atributo src

Comment: es que se ve veria un cuadro de imagen que no se visualiza (no tiene ruta) ya que lo probe con 3 exploradores de internet, por ese motivo lo tengo dentro de un jquery

Comment: *"es que se ve veria un cuadro de imagen que no se visualiza"* -> Pues ocúltalo mientras no tiene imagen y lo muestras cuando la tiene. No necesitas ni quitar la imagen, simplemente pones la imagen que quieres y la muestras, en vez de quitarlo lo ocultas... cuando quieras volver a mostrarlo simplemente cambias la imagen y la muestras de nuevo. No hace falta andar tocando el DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambia el código del botón por este:

```
$('#preview').on('click', '.del', function() {
  $(this).prev('img').remove(); //Quita la imagen del elemento previo al botón "remover"
  $(this).remove();//Quita el botón también
});
```

Comment: Gracias amigo me funciono el codigo se agradece

Comment: @VictorHugo, si te sirvió la respuesta, márcala como aceptada, por favor. Así, otros usuarios con problemas similares sabrán que esto puede servirles.